# Problem of Database is not Added the Data (.Net Framework MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working a project and I have a database or controller problem.

This is my controller part:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ConfirmHotelReservation(int? hotelid, int? customerid)
    {

        TBLHOTELREZERVASYON reservation = new TBLHOTELREZERVASYON();
        reservation.hotel = hotelid;
        reservation.musteri = customerid;
        db.TBLHOTELREZERVASYON.Add(reservation);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This is the cshtml part:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmHotelReservation", "Hotel", new { hotelid = TempData["hotel_id"], customerid = Session["customer_id"] }, FormMethod.Post))
{

    <label style="color:black"> Başlangıç Tarihi</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.baslangic, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
    <br />

    <label style="color:black"> Bitiş Tarihi</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.bitis, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
    <br />

    <label style="color:black">Kişi Sayısı</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.kisi_sayisi, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.person, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />

    <button class="btn btn-info">Onayla</button>
}
```

[image]

**hotelid** and **customerid** added but baslangic,bitis and kisi_sayisi not added
[image]

[image]

```
enter code here
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You aren't setting those values in the first code snippet you posted, how would you expect them to get set?

Comment: you are right I missed this as I'm just starting out. I solved it thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: baslangic, bitis and kisi_sayisi are not bound to parameter of the controller action method that your request is routed to.

(One possible) Solution:

Part 1: getting the data in the controller

Change your controller method definition to:

```
public ActionResult ConfirmHotelReservation(int? hotelid, int? customerid, string baslangic, string bitis, string kisi_sayisi )
```

Part 2: getting the values of those parameters into the database

add the following lines of code to the body of your controller

```
reservation.baslangic= baslangic;
reservation.bitis= bitis;
reservation.kisi_sayisi = kisi_sayisi ;
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#targets-1

Comment: Thank you very much i found another way but this also seems to work